# PhoneGap Android jQuery Mobile app runs on device without CSS/JS

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've got a Phonegap (Cordova 2.0.0) app, built for Android, running with jQuery Mobile + Backbone.js. When I test it on the emulator, it works correctly (runs as in the browser, CSS and JS appear, etc).

When I sign it and install it on a non-debug device, it runs but without the CSS and JS (so basically shows an unstyled HTML document which doesn't run the JS).

The body of my app is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My App</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />

     <script src="http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libraries/cordova-2.0.0-ios.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libraries/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="libraries/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="libraries/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>
        <script src="libraries/detect.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/sha1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>           

    <script type="text/javascript">

          var jqmReady = $.Deferred();
        var deviceReady = $.Deferred();

        /**
         * on load - manages dependency between jquery mobile and phonegap
         */
        function onBodyLoad()
        {
          // get device
          $.os = {};
        $.os.android = navigator.platform.indexOf("android")>=0;
        $.os.ios = navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone")>=0 || navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad")>=0;

        // listen to device ready
        if ($.os.android || $.os.ios) {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady.resolve, false);
        }
        else {
          // must be in a browser, so immediately resolve
          deviceReady.resolve();
        }
        }

        $(document).bind("mobileinit", jqmReady.resolve);
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() { console.log('mobileinit'); });
        $(document).bind('pageinit', function() { console.log('pageinit'); });

        // when jquery mobile and device ready, then fire
        $.when(jqmReady, deviceReady).then(function() {
          console.log('Ready');
        // disable push state: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        App.init();
      });

      onBodyLoad();

    </script>           
  </head>
  <body onload="" data-lat="" data-lng="">
```

Has anyone come across this before? I was wondering if it's something to do with the relative paths (rather than absolute?) or how I package it together in Eclipse. Also, on an iPhone it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you include your css and js files ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />

Comment: maybe its better if you show the entire HTML file (until the body tag is sufficient) :)

Comment: Oops sorry I only pasted some of it, I've edited the body now

Comment: I should further mention that I've looked at the contents of the APK (unzipped), and all the CSS files are in there - indeed, when I run the index.html file in a browser on my Mac, it launches correctly. So I know the asset files have been packaged in.

Comment: In my case, I was loading some js files like  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>` and my device wasn't able to access the internet, so my HTML form was loading without it. It seems to be different in your case.